# JSON-array to MyObject []

Tags: angular

I need to serialize JSON to an Object. Thats working well.

e.g. JSON-data:

```
{"a":"111", "b":"222"}
```

Class representing the model:

```
export class MyObj
{
    public a : string;
    public b : string;

    public deserialize (data : any) : MyObj
    {
      Object.assign (this, data);
      return this;
    }
}
```

How I get the JSON-data and convert it to MyObj:

```
return this.http.get ("http://mydata").pipe (map (resp => new MyObj ().deserialize (resp)));
```

But how do I need tochange the http-get to get MyObj [] if the JSON-data is now a list??

Output of the HTTP-servers handler:

```
[{"a":"111","b":"222"},{"a":"333","b":"444"}]
```

If I try

```
   getit () : Observable <Array <MyObj>>
   {
       let x = this.http.get ("http://mydata").pipe (map (resp => resp.map  (l => new MyObj ().deserialize (l))));
       console.log ("x=" +x);
       return x;
   }
```

Output of console is

```
x=[object Object]
```

Output of angular is

```
... Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Why does the JSON not appear as list??

**EDIT**

After some analytics and tests with trichetriche (big thank you!) we found out that is seems to be a Mozilla problem. His solution is correct in Chromium as well as in Blitz.

**EDIT**

I'd like to add the solution that works for me now.

```
 list () : Observable <MyObj []>
 {
     return this.http.get <MyObj []>("http://localhost:8888/archive/foo")
      .pipe (map (resp => resp.map (line => new MyObj ().deserialize (line))));
 }
```

Setting the type for get <> is important. Otherwise Typescript would expect resp is Object and not Object []. And then .map would not be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` :

```js
return this.http
  .get("http://mydata")
  .pipe(
    map(resp => resp.map(line => new MyObj().deserialize(line)))
  );
```

Comment: read the question there is a line `Object.assign (this, input);` in the model from where this `input` will get passed using this answer

`.pipe( map(resp` here resp will be full http response object not an array so resp.map never exists

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: @chris this means your response isn't `resp = [{"a":"111", "b":"222"}, {"a":"333", "b":"444"}]`, and isn't a list. Remove the last line of your answer if this isn't the case.

Comment: @jitender `resp = [{"a":"111", "b":"222"}, {"a":"333", "b":"444"}]`. This is an array, so you can use `map`. But apparently this isn't the case, as the OP said he has an error.

Comment: @chris01 `console.log` you response and edit your question with this log. If it is an array, then my answer applies.

Comment: I edited. But I can confirm the JSON-data is as I said.

Comment: Then you aren't receiving a list, please remove the list from your question.

Comment: @chris01 and while we're at it, edit your whole question to specify what you are asking, since the whole point of your question was to apply the instanciation to a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176714/discussion-between-chris01-and-trichetriche).